# Blur Interfaces of TeXworks on MacBook Pro with Retina Display？

Tags: macbook-pro, display, latex

I am using TeXworks as the LaTeX editor on my new MacBook Pro with Retina Display.

The interfaces are super blur. It seems that TeXworks does not support the retina resolution. See below.

[image]

The MacTeX.pkg was downloaded from [MacTeX TUG](http://tug.org/mactex/) today. Hence, I think it is the latest version.

How may I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

#### You can use [**Retinizer**](http://retinizer.mikelpr.com):

> [image]
>
> **Retinizer** is a small app I wrote that **allows apps that aren’t retina** ready and are displayed pixelated at 1x **to display** their UI widgets **at 2x**. That way, only their custom images will look bad and not the whole app.

Tested, and works great:

Before:
[image: @1x]

After:
[image: @2x]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use TexShop, which also comes in the bundle. It looks quite good on a retina display and is quite similar to TexWorks otherwise:

[image: TexShop screenshot]